# Dynamic Filename

Tags: vbscript, alteryx

I'm creating a simple workflow with Run Command Tool, I need to run the macro inside the macro-enabled file. But I want my workflow to be dynamic, So I've inserted a File Browser Tool to select the ".xlsm" file and run the macro using Run Command Tool.

[image: Sample]

This is my VBScript

```
dim fso: set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
dim CurrentDirectory    
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
CurrentDirectory = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(ThisWorkbook.Path)
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(CurrentDirectory & "\*.xlsm")
objExcel.Application.Visible = True
objExcel.Application.Run "ClearContents"
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
objExcel.Application.Quit
WScript.Echo "Finished."
WScript.Quit
```

For eg. I've selected the ".xlsm" file using File Browser Tool, How can I use that file and run the macro inside that file that I've select.

As you can see in my VBScript I've set the path and filename static. How can I change that base on the file that I've select?

Comment: Read through [the documentation](https://help.alteryx.com/current/designer/run-command-tool) maybe that will help.

Comment: Think [this article](https://community.alteryx.com/t5/Alteryx-Designer/Run-command-tool-questions/td-p/185613) might help you, talks about using `%Type.Name%` in your batch or script *(see the [Hello World example](https://community.alteryx.com/t5/Alteryx-Designer/Run-command-tool-questions/m-p/185651/highlight/true#M48002) in the linked article)*. I don't use [tag:alteryx] so it's difficult to test but hopefully, this should be enough for you to have a go at.

Comment: Use a `Block Until Done` tool to first write out the `script.vbs` file with whatever mods you want, and then execute your Run command.